# Reference doesnt seem to be picked up when published to web server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, pdf, reference

I am using ExpertPDF to convert HTML to a PDF.  I have added the relevent libraries into the bin folder and added the reference to it.

This works fine when I run it through Visual Studio 2010 but when I try to publish it to the web server and try it I get nothing.  When I use Firefox I get XML Parser errors.

The dll file is being copied across locally to the web server.

Does anyone have any ideas why it would be working in VS2010 but not on the live web server?

Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, but it sounds likely that the assemblies you copy over to the server have dependencies that exist in your dev environment, but not the server.  If there was any installation process in the dev environment, you'll as a minimum need to replicate parts of that to the server.

Comment: The problem was the assembly wasnt registered.  After running RegAsm (I think it was that) it worked correctly.